# Software Center doesn't launch, and no software visible in Unity

Tags: unity, software-center

On a fresh install UBUNTU 11.10.

Cannot open the Software center, when I launch it by command line it display me an error : "Erreur de
segmentation". Also I cannot access to my software installed thru Unity, no software listed and no possibility to search for a software installed (example Thundebird).

The software update can be run but are not updated. I neet to do a "sudo
apt-get upgrade" for having the latest updates availables in the update
software.

It seems that's these problems are connected because they appeard at the
same time. After few use of the fresh install (shutdown and restart).

I'm desperate... My system is fresh it should run correctly.
I also try to uninstall software update and software center en reinstall them and still the same problem.....

Please Help !

Comment: I just *know* I've seen this question asked before, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 1):

I think your package list is broken... I too faced this issue which I resolved by running the following commands

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. The problem is the same after these command line (I restarted the computer). Still no software in the unity search and impossible to run the software center. Any other suggestions. Maybe I can try to repair the system with the Ubuntu live CD maybe there is an option for that ?

Comment: u can try installing synaptic package manager from command line and use that!

   sudo apt-get install synaptic

this is the old package manager

Comment: Yes I know that but I cannot acces to the software center and also I cannot list my software on Unity.... This is not the solution.